# datepicker not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a Jquery UI datepicker control in my asp.net MVC application and it works fine in IE and Firefox but it doens't work in chrome when I click the datepicker button. Here is my Index view:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        autoSize: true,
        altField: "input#txtDate",
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/LiveGame/Partial3?gameDate=" + dateText,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(result) {
                    var domElement = $(result);
                    $("#dvGames").html(domElement);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $("#txtDate").val($.format.date(new Date(), 'dd MMM yyyy'));

    $('#dvGames').load(
    '<%= Url.Action("Partial3", "LiveGame") %>',
    { gameDate: $("#txtDate").val() }
);
});
```

Here is my partial:

```
  public ActionResult Partial3(string gameDate)
      {             
                return PartialView("Partial3", gameDate);
      }


 <div id="dvGames" class="cornerdate1">                            

                                <%= Url.Action("LiveGame","Partial3") %>            
                              </div>
                            <input type="text" id="txtDate" name="txtDate" readonly="readonly" class="cornerdate" />
                            <input id="datepicker" class="cornerimage" type="image" src="../../Content/images/calendar.gif" alt="date" />                
                             </div>
```

Comment: can you provide some code so we can figure out why is that happening ?

Comment: Hi anasnakawa: I have updated the question, Please find the code.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use the Datepicker option from jquery ui

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button", //add this line
        buttonImage: "path/to-your-image.gif", //add this line
        buttonImageOnly: true //add this line
    });
});
</script>
```

Or you add a click event on the button:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input#datepicker").click(function() {
            $("input#datepicker").datepicker("show");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the AJAX `success` function you are casting the result to a DOM element. Try simply to do this:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $('#dvGames').load(
        '<%= Url.Action("Partial3", "LiveGame") %>', 
        { gameDate: dateText }
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried this but It is not working. When I click the datepicker button, calendar does't popup. I have added the datepicker html in question.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, is the `Partial3` action hit?